# white-space nowrap breaking the column layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Without `white-space: nowrap`:

[column layout works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/b20qsmg7/2/)

With `white-space: nowrap`:

[column layout breaks](https://jsfiddle.net/b20qsmg7/3/)

How can I avoid breaking this column layout?

```css
.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
.col, .col-1, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-auto, .col-lg, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-auto, .col-md, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-auto, .col-sm, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-auto, .col-xl, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-auto {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.col {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.col-2 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 16.666667%;
    flex: 0 0 16.666667%;
    max-width: 16.666667%;
}
.wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  border: solid 4px purple;
  padding: 4px;
}
.wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: lightgrey;
  display: inline-block;
}
p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: lightgreen;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-2">
two
</div>
<div class="col">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</p>
    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</p>
    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: If the text is not allowed to wrap the second column grows more than 100% width, then how can two columns sit side by side?  There simply isn't enough space. What's the expected output?

Comment: I want column layout as before while using white-space: nowrap.

Comment: min-width: 0; to col

Comment: @gacat so you want the text in second column to be one line but truncated?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Wow, it works with min-width: 0. But what's the trick?

Comment: read the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

you can add class container

```
<div class="row container">
<div class="col-2">
two
</div>
<div class="col">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</p>
    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</p>
    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>``
```

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: im not sure what do you want

Comment: see first linked url, I want that column layout but preserving the white-space: nowrap.